# How do I go about showing that $f$ is decreasing if $f'(x) \leq 0$ on $(a, b)$.

Tags: derivatives

Given the differentiable function $f$ on $(a, b)$, how do I go about showing that $f$ is decreasing if $f'(x) \leq 0$ on $(a, b)$.

Comment: What $g$ is for?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem): if $a<x_1<x_2<b$ then
$$f(x_2)-f(x_1)=f'(c)(x_2-x_1)\leq 0$$
for some $c\in(x_1,x_2)$.